# How to load Images from Gallery in Recyclerview in android?

Tags: android, image, gallery

I am trying to Load Images from gallery into my application folder. I am using `Recyclerview`
By using this Intent i am able to select Multiple Images from Gallery but don't know how to get images in my applications folder. Note I have different folders in my application.

```
 private void OpenFromGallery() {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);`}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope it will works for you
[Click here](https://github.com/lovetuzitong/MultiImageSelector)